# According to Kierkegaard, is freedom not possible?

Tags: kierkegaard, freedom

If my understanding is correct, then Kierkegaard (**The Sickness Unto Death**) is saying that freedom is impossible.

What I understand from reading:

Guilt is directly proportional with the realization of freedom. The more realization of the freedom will result in more guilt, in the extreme of that lies depression. This results in guilt hindering this freedom. On the other extreme, the schizophrenic is predetermined and destined to follow a single possibility. Since nobody can choose to become obsessed with a certain possibility and to have pure faith in it, therefore the schizophrenic lacks freedom.

Edit: What i want to say is that the freedom of the self (as in schizophrenia) should not be mixed with the freedom of choice which is the freedom of the consciousness.

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you confusing **guilt** with **despair** ? Also what do you mean by **freedom** in your question?

Comment: "The depressed person uses guilt to hold onto his
objects and to keep his situation unchanged. Otherwise he would
have to analyze it or be able to move out of it and transcend it.
Better guilt than the terrible burden of freedom and responsibility", Ernest Becker , The denial of death.

Comment: Freedom: Being free of guilt, in the same time, without having to be schizophrenic.

Comment: Okay not seeing any references to *Sickness unto Death* in the question or the quote and terms that are not used that way by the author make it kind of hard to answer ...